# External_query with dynamic query - Error: Connection argument in EXTERNAL_QUERY must be a literal string or query parameter

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to call external_query with dynamically created query string in BigQuery Web UI.

```
DECLARE extquery STRING;
SET extquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable;";
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-external-conn", extquery);
```

This script gives an error

```
Query error: Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY
Connection argument in EXTERNAL_QUERY must be a literal string or query parameter
```

Is it impossible to do in BigQuery?
What is the right way to pass query as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error states - "Connection argument in EXTERNAL_QUERY must be a literal string or query parameter"
So, "must be a literal string" version would be

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-external-conn", "SELECT * FROM mytable;");
```

It is more complicated with "must be a query parameter"
Note: [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#running_parameterized_queries) and [script variables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery-scripting) are quite different animals - you can check details in respective docs - but to clarify my point :    `extquery` in `SET extquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable;";` is **not a parameter** but rather **script variable**

Meantime, BigQuery UI (neither Classic nor Console) do not support Parameterized Queries, but you still can make it using CLI, API or clients of your choice

Below example is for CLI

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--parameter='extquery::SELECT * FROM mytable;' \
'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-external-conn", @extquery)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole query into a dynamic query, and use execute_immediate to show results:

```
declare query_string string;
set query_string = "SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY('my-external-conn', \""||extquery||"\")";
execute immediate query_string;
```