# Passing parameters to external query inside stored procedure in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to call external query inside stored procedure in BigQuery.

Something along the lines

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dataset.my_procedure(param1 STRING)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-external-connection", """
      SELECT * FROM external_table WHERE column1=:param1
    """) as external;
END;
```

Is it possible to pass parameter to external query and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ONLY option I see for you (at least as of today - because ""Connection argument in EXTERNAL_QUERY must be a literal string or query parameter"" and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61294646/5221944 for little more details on this)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dataset.my_procedure(param1 STRING)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-external-connection", """
      SELECT * FROM external_table
    """)
    WHERE column1 = param1;
END;
```

So, you just simply moving WHERE clause to outside ...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in this case it would read the whole external table to temporary BQ table, and only then apply the filter? In case of a big table this is not feasible.

Comment: as I said - this is the only option as of today if you want to make it - unfortunate but it is! you can post feature request for this to be done right way

Comment: Thank you. I created an feature request - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154388185

Comment: great. starred it too - also we have chance to see if BQ Team has something under the belt right away - they always do have something :o)